# How can I get those two figure aligned?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

As you see, I create the graphics in the same document. I would like that Figure one and Figure two are written in the same line and not one more upwards.

```
\documentclass[english,12pt,oneside, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{filecontents}{innovation.tex}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [node distance=.8cm,
  start chain=going below,]
     \node[punktchain, join] (intro) {Buyer a};
     \node[punktchain, join] (probf)      {Multiple  dddddddddddddddddddddddddd$e_i$ in R\&D};
     \node[punktchain, join] (investeringer)      {Multiple  bids $(y_i,p_i)$};
     \node[punktchain, join] (perfekt) {Buyer s};
     \node[punktchain, join] (perfekt) {Supplier};      
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{filecontents}

  \begin{filecontents}{supply.tex}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [node distance=.8cm,
  start chain=going below,]
     \node[punktchain, join] (intro) {Buyer announces $V(y)$};
     \node[punktchain, join] (probf)      {Multiple };
     \node[punktchain, join] (investeringer)      {Buye};
     \node[punktchain, join] (perfekt) {Su
     \node[punktchain, join] (perfekt) {Su};      
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{filecontents}


\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \input{innovation} % first figure itself
        \caption{first figure}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \input{supply} % second figure itself
        \caption{second figure}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \input{innovation} % first figure itself
        \caption{first figure}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \input{supply} % second figure itself
        \caption{second figure}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `baseline={(some,coordinate)}` I guess

Comment: Please make sure your example actually works. `\begin{document}` is in the wrong place, there's at least one `tikzlibrary` missing, and the `punktchain` style is undefined.

Comment: Does it work properly if both minipages start like `\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}`? I.e. with the `[b]` added.